# Image thumbnail not showing for many2Many field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have a many2many image field and I am using many2many_binary widget. When I am uploading images it doesn't show the image thumbnail.

XML Code:

```
<record id="variant_image_upload_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">variant.image.upload.form</field>
        <field name="model">variant.image.upload</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Images">
                <group>
                <field name="product_code" readonly="1"></field>
                <field name="color"></field>
                </group>
                <group>
                <field name="images" widget="many2many_binary" string="attach"></field>
                </group>

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

.py

```
images = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', string="Image")
```

[image]